# Google maps API to avoid google authorization key?

Tags: google-api

I just stumbled upon this piece of code on the Google developers website, copy pasting it to test tells me it doesn't need API access key from Google to work.

```
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemaps'),
        mapOptions);
  }

  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
        'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

I know Google has limit of 25K API calls per day, so am I doing something illegal?

Comment: Parts of the API don't require a key - the parts that do would return an error otherwise and your script wouldn't work so **no**, it's no big deal.

Comment: @Emissary makes sense, where do I read which parts require key?

Comment: Each of the APIs is documented [`[maps v3 api]`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) - the first sentence is perhaps misleading.  It states you *should* include an api key - but it's not necessary.  If you are using the service freely it facilitates tracking (and would be required if you exceeded the quota) but 25K is a ***Huge*** limit.

Comment: ^ baring in mind that your queries are cached - so it's not the same as "page views".  If visitor (A) views your webpage a query is made to the API.  When visitor (B) comes along, the cached API request is served - and doesn't count towards your usage.